# Datetime Arrives to Server Converted to UTC

Tags: c#, json, datetime

We are running .NET Core 2.1 on Linux. We do a POST with body below, and it seems for all 3 cases the datetime is converted to UTC time, instead of keeping the local time with offset as submitted. What is surprising is that even JSON properties deserialized to string are still showing converted value.

We are trying to retain the local value for further processing.

JSON:

```
{
    "ts": "2020-09-27T01:23:27.047-04:00",
    "tsTest": "2020-09-27T01:23:27.047-04:00",
    "tsTest2": "2020-09-27T01:23:27.047-04:00"
}
```

Model:

```
public class HealthAssessmentResponseDto
    {
        [JsonProperty("ts")]
        // public string LocalDttmStr { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset LocalDttm { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tsTest")]
        public string LocalDttmStr { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tsTest2")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK")]
        public DateTimeOffset LocalDttmConverted { get; set; }
    }

    public class DateFormatConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter
    {
        public DateFormatConverter(string format)
        {
            DateTimeFormat = format;
        }
    }
```

Result

```
{
    "tranId": "7be8989c-c310-4b7a-a5a2-1706398f94f8",
    "payload": {
        "rto": true,
        "message": "LocalDttmStr: 2020-09-27T05:23:27, LocalDttmConverted: 09/27/2020 05:23:27 +00:00, DatetimeOffset: 09/27/2020 05:23:27 +00:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could produce a [mcve] which doesn't need to receive a request from anywhere - just loads a JSON file from disk, parses it, and then displays the result of that, including showing the code for *how* you're displaying the result. That would make it easier to help you, partly because we could all reproduce it easily.

Comment: The datetimes are correct and should not be changed since they include a TimeZone.  You should not make any changes to the code except when you output the datetime as a string you can format date to whatever format you like.  I do not think this is an import issue.  It is an output issue.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need any custom converter or to change the default json settings.